# private chat using socket.id on socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

i am fresher at nodejs and socket.io. i am trying to made a chat application using nodejs, socket.io and angularjs in express framework. i am lacking basic idea how chat is performed privately.up to this stage my code works chatting in a group of connected users. here is my server code

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket = require('./routes/socket.js');
server.listen(8000);
console.log('server listening on port:8000');
io.on('connection',socket);
```

and my main socket file consit code like:

```
module.exports = function(socket){   
console.log('connected'+' '+'socketId :'+socket.id);     
//console.log(req.session.id);
var users =[];
socket.emit(socket.id);

socket.on('username',function(data){
    users.push({id:socket.id,message:data.username});        
    socket.emit('username', users)

})      
  socket.on('typing',function(data){
    //socket.emit('typing',{message:"helo angular"});
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing',{message:data.message});
});
  socket.on('typing-stop',function(data){
    //socket.emit('typing',{message:"helo angular"});
    debugger;
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing-stop',{message:data.message});
});
socket.on('new-user',function(data){
    socket.emit('new-user',data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('new-user',data);
})   

socket.on('message',function(data){
    users.push({message:data.message});        
    socket.emit('message',{id:socket.id,message:data.message});
    socket.broadcast.emit('message',{id:socket.id,message:data.message});// emit the message to every one connected in server
})

socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');          
      socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected',{'message':'user left the chat room'});
    });
 }
```

i am abe to load all the users who get logged in my app.
all i want is to click to the available and start private messaging, till now chat is public everyone connected in server can see message.
my angularjs  controller code goes like:

```
    function orgController(notifyService, chatSocket, $state,$http) {
    chatSocket.connect();

    var vm = this;
    vm.sendMessage = sendMessage;
    vm.messages = [];
    vm.users = [];      

    var id = $state.params.id;
    $http.get('/users/' + id).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data);
    vm.userData = result.data;
    chatSocket.emit('new-user', { 'username': result.data.details.firstName             + ' ' + result.data.details.lastName });
     });
      chatSocket.on('new-user',function(data){
    vm.users.push(data);
    })
    function sendMessage(msg) {
    //console.log(msg);
    if (msg != null && msg != '') {
        chatSocket.emit('message', { message: msg });
        vm.msg = '';
    } else {
        vm.msg = '';
    }
    }
    chatSocket.on('message', function(data) {
    //debugger;
    console.log(data);
    vm.messages.push(data);
    });
}
```

NOTE: i have included angular-socket.io modules and inject its dependency in a service called **chatSocket** which only return socketFactory.

now i want to click in a user from logged in userlist and start communication. how can i do it  from (socket.id). which socket generates or from session id? anyone has better way of doing such. any suggestion and response are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is emit an event to a specific socket like this.

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('privateMessage', {message: <message goes here>});
```

then on the client side

```
socket.on('privateMessage', function(data){
  var message = data.message;
  //do stuff, display message etc...
});
```

Comment: i have a separate js file under routes folder which codes is like:
module.exports = function(socket){
  socket.on('message',function(data){
    //console.log(data);               
        //socket.emit('message',{message:data.message});
        socket.broadcast.to(data.id).emit('message',{'message':data.message,'id':data.id,'name':data.name});// emit the message to every one connected in server
    })
}
is'nt its correct ? i dont get message

Comment: I'm not sure 100% what you are trying to do here. You are receiving a message, and then using socket.emit, then also using socket.broadcast. Are you wanting to send this part to everyone? Or only one certain socket?